# Is there a steady state for two conductors at different temperatures connected to a battery?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, conductors, non-equilibrium, thermoelectricity

In order to understand better nonequilibrium statistical physics I came up with the following thought experiment. I wonder what are the requirements to obtain a steady state.

Let us consider two identical conductors $A$ and $B$, with initial temperatures $T_A$ and $T_B$, respectively. $T_A>T_B$ and there aren’t any temperature reservoirs.

Let us suppose that the two can only exchange electrons. The geometry does not matter; you can choose one if that helps.

Let us consider that there is an applied electric voltage $\Delta V$ provided by a battery connected between two bodies such that (in the case were the temperatures were the same) electrons would flow from object $A$ to object $B$.

Let the system evolve. After a long time has passed, I was wondering if the system would reach a steady state.

### What I have considered

The only steady state I can think of, is one where object $B$ heats up with respect to $A$, in such a way that the new $\Delta T$ together with the $\Delta V$ leads to a zero net current. Another possibility is that the two bodies reach some temperature, but that the current flows steadily. Of course, the other solution is that the answer to the question is negative: the bodies heat up and up indefinitely thanks to the power provided by the potential difference and there aren’t any steady state and heat sinks.

Comment: Can you describe the setup you are envisioning in more detail? What kind of thermal contact exists between $A$ and $B$? Only through the electrical contact? How is the circuit being closed?

Comment: @BySymmetry I do not care much about the details, the two bodies could be just in contact or connected through a wire. The two would also be connected to a battery providing the potential difference.

Comment: These questions cannot be ignored in determining what the steady state looks like. You are pumping charge from $A$ to $B$. Does that charge build up or does it go somewhere else? That charge can carry energy, which effects the temperature. Is this the only channel for energy to be transported or are there others?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137483/discussion-on-question-by-mauricio-is-there-a-steady-state-for-two-conductors-at).

Comment: 1) What do you mean by *"until in produces"*? Do you mean *"until it produces"*? Or something else? 2) There seems to be a formatting error near "`$Bp`".

Comment: @PeterMortensen edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a sketch of how we might consider equilibrium for this scenario (specifically, by looking for an entropy maximum at $dS=0$).

We write the relevant [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) for each (assumed constant-volume) conductor $i$ as

$$\require{cancel}
dU_i=T_i\,dS_i-\cancelto{0}{P\,dV_i}+\bar\mu_i\,dN_i,$$

with energy $U$, temperature $T$, entropy $S$, electrochemical potential $\bar\mu=\mu+zFV$ (where $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $z$ is the signed charge number of the relevant charge carrier, $F$ is Faraday’s constant, and $V$ is the voltage), and charge carrier number $N$.

Joule heating will dissipate energy in the conductors, leading to a temperature increase as mediated by the heat capacity. We can express these relations as

$$\frac{dU_i}{dt}\left(=C_i\frac{dT_i}{dt}\right)=I^2R_i+\dot U_{i,\text{other}},$$

where $t$ is time, $C$ is the heat capacity, $I$ is the circuit current, $R$ is the resistance, and $\dot U_{i,\text{other}}$ is any energy transfer rate or power dissipation other than Joule heating (e.g., thermoelectric).

In addition,

$$I=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{\sum_i R_i}+I_\text{other},$$

where $\mathcal{E}$ is the applied voltage ($\Delta V$ in your nomenclature, renamed here to avoid confusion with the voltage at other parts of the circuit) and $I_\text{other}$ is any current other than ohmic (e.g., thermoelectric).

Then, we seek an entropy maximum, for which

$$dS=\sum_idS_i=\sum_i\left(\frac{dU_i}{T_i}-\frac{\bar\mu_i}{T_i}dN_i\right)=0.$$

(If we remove the applied voltage $\mathcal{E}$ and consider a real wire that can transfer nonelectronic heat, we have $dU_1=-dU_2$ by conservation of energy and $dN_1=-dN_2$ by conservation of charge. Since $dU_i$ and $dN_i$ can vary independently—through uncoupled heat and charge transfer—we recover the expected $T_1=T_2$ and $\bar\mu_1=\bar\mu_2$.)

Comment: If I understand your answer, you are saying that this equations are the way to calculate the final steady state but you cannot make any specific conclusion without further details?

Comment: Yes; I've been reviewing some thermoelectricity texts (*Continuum theory and modeling of thermoelectric elements*, *Modern Theory of Thermoelectricity*) and think I'll stop here.

Answer (score -1):

Heat flows from the hot metal to the cold metal, independent of the Peltier effect.

Given incoming electrical power, the Peltier effect may pump heat in the opposite direction, potentially maintaining a temperature difference, but there's a serious problem in the system design here: "there aren’t any temperature reservoirs".

The device does no work, so all electrical power provided is dissipated as heat.

Without a "temperature reservoir" (heat sink), the electrical dissipation, necessary to maintain a temperature difference, adds heat to the system. The Peltier effect can move that heat between the metals, but it can't eliminate it from the system.

Thus, if electrical power is supplied, the system temperature increases without limit due to the continuously added heat (in reality, something breaks or melts). Thus, the only steady state is with no electrical power applied, thus no Peltier effect, and no temperature difference.

Comment: Would that change drastically if the air around it worked as a heat sink at a (fixed temperature everywhere)? Would there still not be a steady state?

Comment: @Mauricio You'd get a steady state if the heat loss was sufficient to keep the device from melting.

Comment: Last question, so if there is a good heat sink, the current will be constant in the steady state, right?

Comment: Yep. We operate the Peltier heat pumps on NICER (https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/nicer/) at constant current, and that yields a steady detector temperature, given a steady radiator temperature.

Comment: This answer displays a lack of understanding of thermoelectricty and thermodynamics.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik In what way? I know a bit about Peltier heat pumps, having successfully designed detector coolers for spacecraft instruments.

Comment: This website doesn't allow for discussion (comments will get erased after a while). In short: 1) the heat flux can have any direction, and in particular it can have the exact opposite direction to the temperature gradient (this comes from the generalized Fourier's law $\vec{J_Q}=-\kappa \nabla T + ST\vec{J}$, where $\vec J$'s direction can be tuned.
2) You ignored Thomson heat, which adds up onto Joule heat. It turns out it can be a cooling, and it can beat Joule heat (it depends on the Thomson coefficient, and on the magnitudes of $\nabla T$ and $|\vec{J}|$, meaning that the statement that

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Quite an abstract argument. For what concrete materials and experimental arrangement does it hold? Stars, for example, don't count: the question is about solid conductors.

Comment: Are you asking for 1) or 2)? For 1), any material with non zero S, as long as the magnitude of $\nabla T$ and $\vec J$ are carefully selected.  For 2), any material, again, as long as $\mu = T dS/dT$ is non zero, and that $\vec J$ and $\nabla T$ is carefully selected so that $\mu \nabla T \cdot \vec J < -\rho |\vec J|^2$.  There is virtually no restriction on the material(s). Note that I didn't consider anisotropic materials, in which case there is another heat/cooling term that can also beat Joule heat, too.

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik Can you demonstrate this in an experiment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137696/discussion-between-untreated-paramediensis-karnik-and-john-doty).